# DialogFragment empty, even though xml provided

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to create a popup with a DialogFragment, however my dialog only contains the title, negative and positive button.

Layout_selection_dialog

```
<Button
        android:text="Aalborg"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/firstCityBtn"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
<Button
        android:text="Aarhus"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/thirdCityBtn"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
<Button
        android:text="København"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/secondCityBtn"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>
```

SelectionDialog

```
public class SelectionDialog extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_selection_dialog, null);

        builder.setTitle("Vælg by").setNegativeButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            }
        }).setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Function to call in the MainActivity

```
fun showCitySelection() {
   var dialog: CitySelectionDialog = CitySelectionDialog()
   var ft: FragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    dialog.show(ft, null)
}
```

Any ideas why I'm not getting my buttons in the dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created `View` but didn't set it to dialog. Add

```
builder.setView(view);
```